# Is there any way to write code for pattern printings in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

While writing pattern printing codes in react I just print using document.write, but is there any way to print * without using dom elements?

Comment: can provide a code snippet

Comment: You mean console output? `console.log("text you wish to print")`

Comment: Not about using console...I need to write a program for pattern pritning in react js ...in that inorder to print  what should I use instead of document.write..